# Is there a way to save/export the curvature direction generated in meshlab?

Tags: meshlab

I'm looking for a way to save (either to a texture or vertex colors) the principal curvature (max) direction for a mesh. Meshlab can generate and display it but I cannot find a way to save it.

I have found a question on this topic before concluding it could not, but it was 3 years old and wondering if anything has changed?

If not, does anyone happen to know of any other software in which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, meshlab is still not capable of saving principal curvatures and there is no plans to implement it.

Regarding to alternatives using another program, libIGL is the answer you are looking for. The tutorial includes a code example that computes principal curvatures in a robust way.

- This is the [tutorial section for curvature directions](https://libigl.github.io/tutorial/#curvature-directions)
- This is the [c++ code example that compute principal curvatures](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/tree/master/tutorial/203_CurvatureDirections/main.cpp). In that code, `PD1` and `PD2` contains the direction of principal curvatures. `PV1` and `PV2` contains the magnitude values of principal curvatures. `H` contains the mean curvature, built by averaging values in `PD1` and `PD2`.
- This is the result of the code example
  [image: principal curvatures]

Answer (score 0):

1. Filters  /  Color Creation and Processing  /  Colorize Curvature (APSS).
2. Adjust colors w/ Quality Mapper (Rainbow Bunny Button) and/or Filters  /  Color Creation and Processing  /  Vertex ______
3. Filters  /  Color Creation and Processing  /  Transfer Color: Vertex to Face
4. Export mesh as Alias Wavefront Object (.obj), be sure to check Face: Color